# How do I instantiate an object of a class that will generate and return an object of another class?

Tags: c++, queue, instantiation

This is the actual question.  Instantiate an object of the given class: AirPlaneGenerator that will generate and return an AirPlane object whenever the interval time (set during instantiation) has elapsed.  NOTE: the generator will return NULL between intervals; signifying that no plane is currently landing. 
This is the cpp file for the airport generator file

```
    #include "airplanegenerator.h"
        // initialize the static list of tasks
    vector<AirPlane> AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes(0);
    // -- Constructors --
     // default constructor
    AirPlaneGenerator::AirPlaneGenerator(int i) {
// initialise all airplanes within the list
this->interval = i;
this->cursor = 0;
this->elapsed = 0;

     AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new      

      AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));

      AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new    
    AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new  
    AirPlane(JFF_VIP));

    AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new  
     AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
 AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new   
     AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new   
     AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new   
     AirPlane(JFF_VIP));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new   
     AirPlane(JFF_VIP));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
     AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new   
     AirPlane(JFF_SMALLPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new  
    AirPlane(JFF_SMALLPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_SMALLPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new  
    AirPlane(JFF_VIP));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_LARGEPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
     AirPlane(JFF_LARGEPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new    
    AirPlane(JFF_SMALLPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
     AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
     AirPlane(JFF_LARGEPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
     AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
     AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_LARGEPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_SMALLPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new     
    AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_MAIL));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_SMALLPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_VIP));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_LARGEPASS));
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.insert(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes.end(), new 
    AirPlane(JFF_GOVERNMENT));
cout << " GENERATOR: AirPlanes Are Ready For Landing." << endl;
}
// -- Other Interfaces --
// get the next task in the list
AirPlane* AirPlaneGenerator::getNext() {
     // find out the current elapsed time
    this->elapsed += 1;
    // return an airplane if the elapsed time exceeds the current cursor position
     if (this->elapsed / this->interval >= 1) {
    this->elapsed -= this->interval;
    if (this->cursor < TOTALPLANES) {
        cout << " GENERATOR: AirPlane# " <<   
AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes[this->cursor].getIdnum() << " Now Landing." << endl;
        return &(AirPlaneGenerator::lstPlanes[this->cursor++]);
    } else {
        cout << " GENERATOR: No More AirPlanes In The Air To Land." << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    } else {
    cout << " GENERATOR: No AirPlane Landing Now." << endl;
    return NULL;
   }
}
```

Comment: I know how to make an object but I just don't understand what the question wants me to do

Answer (score 0):

Question is you need to implement Creational Pattern ([Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)), which will create object of class after given interval time.

Comment: thanks for responding..first I'm hearing about this factory pattern..will have a read

Comment: That is design pattern, which is really easy(easiest) to understand.

Comment: the class posted is a given one to be worked with. I dont think I should tamper with it ie.the design. This design method should be implemented in main?